# С++ Клиент-Сервер, WinSoket, передается только часть буфера

Tags: c++, сокет, сокеты

Есть код на сервере

```
#define INFO_BUFFER_SIZE 32767
TCHAR  infoBuf[INFO_BUFFER_SIZE];
DWORD  bufCharCount = INFO_BUFFER_SIZE;
GetComputerName(infoBuf, &bufCharCount);
_tprintf(TEXT("Имя компьютера : %s\n"), (CHAR*)infoBuf);
send(clients[ID], (CHAR*)infoBuf, INFO_BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
```

Выводит `Имя компьютера : PC`

Есть код на клиенте

```
#define INFO_BUFFER_SIZE 32767
char cResponse[INFO_BUFFER_SIZE];
retVal = recv(clientSock1, cResponse, INFO_BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
printf("Имя компьютера: %s\n", cResponse);
```

Выводит `Имя компьютера : P`

Итак вопрос почему передается только часть буфера?

Comment: Возможно, передается юникодная строка, а клиент ее как ASCII пытается выводить. Отладчиком смотрите что реально в буфер помещается.

Comment: Вот так интересно передается https://goo.gl/dnECMZ, не подскажите как так получилось?)

Comment: 1) у вас винегрет из одно- и двух- байтовых символов; 2) возвращаемые значения функций не проверяются; 3) при отправке вы указываете количество элементов в массиве, а не количество байт в нем; 4) при отправке вы указываете размер буфера, а не количество передаваемых данных; 5) размер посылаемого и принимаемого буфера может не совпадать;

Answer (score 0):

Судя по прикрепленному в комментариях скрину из отладчика, передается действительно юникодная строка. А выводится на клиенте - ASCII-строка. В юникодной строке каждый символ представлен двумя байтами, причем для латинских букв второй байт - нулевой, и он считается терминатором строки, если она обрабатывается как ASCII. Вот и выводится только первая буква.

Возможное решение - использовать `wprintf` вместо `printf`.